# Defining an infinite family of classes "MatrixMxN" in C#

Tags: c#, types, matrix-multiplication, language-design, type-safety

Suppose I was writing a linear algebra library in C#, and I wanted to implement matrix multiplication. Of course, two matrices `A` and `B` can only be multiplied to form `AB` if `A` has as many columns as `B` has rows. Hence one would typically include an argument validation step in the definition of multiplication, throwing an error in case of a mismatch. This is how it is done in the [MathNet.Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix) library, which I have been using recently. However, wouldn't it be better if the matrix dimensionality was part of the type definition?

If the matrix dimensions were part of the type definition, then such dimensional mismatch could be caught at compile time instead of run-time. This would also be useful for constraining the shape of matrices in other contexts, such as when implementing mathematical functions that are only defined for square matrices. In particular, it would not be possible to introduce bugs by forgetting to validate matrix dimensions.

However, to implement this we would need some language mechanism that lets us define an infinite (at least in theory) family of classes, all of the form `MatrixMxN` with `M` and `N` being natural numbers describing the matrix dimensions. From what I know, this is not possible in C#, but maybe there is some way? We can define a generic class `Matrix<T1,T2>`, but unless we can create one type `T` for each natural number I don't see how this would get us anywhere. I notice that some functional languages has something called "type-level naturals" which seems to correspond to this latter idea.

So, is there a way to implement something like what I have described above? If not in C#, then how about in other languages?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332392/type-safe-matrix-multiplication) seems to be related, but it discusses Haskell specifically.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018972/type-level-encoding-of-natural-numbers-in-f) might be relevant as well. It concerns F#, so at least a little bit closer to C#.

Comment: Perhaps instead one might have a single Matrix class and implement static checking with a [custom analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)? I don't know how flexible custom analyzers are though, and either way it seems like a pretty inelegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as C# goes, no there is no such mechanism. If there was, Microsft themselves wouldn't have to do this for defining the varied Type Parameter counts of `Tuple<T>`

```
public static Tuple<T1> Create<T1>(T1 item1) {
    return new Tuple<T1>(item1);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
    return new Tuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3) {
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3>(item1, item2, item3);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4) {
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(item1, item2, item3, item4);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5) {
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6) {
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6, T7 item7) {
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7);
}

public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6, T7 item7, T8 item8) {
    return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, new Tuple<T8>(item8));
}
```

For further fun, check out the entirety of the [Tuple.cs source file](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/tuple.cs).

Comment: The request here wasn't for a varying number of generic type parameters (like needed by `Action<>`, `Tuple<>`, `Func<>`) but to have exactly two generic non-type parameters (like C++ supports non-type template parameters)