# Can i define type-level naturals in F#, then use them in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, types, f#, language-design

In [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440892/defining-an-infinite-family-of-classes-matrixmxn-in-c-sharp) I wondered if there is some way in C# to implement matrix dimensionality as a type-level property. That is, I wanted to be able to declare a generic family of classes of the form `Matrix<M, N>`, where `M` and `N` are natural numbers. The ultimate goal was to have dimensionality checks at compile-time, so that, for example, trying to multiply a 3x3 matrix by a 2x3 matrix should yield a compile-time error, or having functions that only accept square matrices (`Matrix<M, M>`).

Unfortunately it does not seem like this is possible in C#, the issue being that `M` and `N` in the generic type `Matrix<M, N>` have to be types, not integers. Some other languages seem to have mechanisms that get around this issue however:

1. Some functional languages, such as Haskell, have the possibility to define type-level naturals. If this were possible in C#, then it should also be possible to define `Matrix<M, N>`, with `M` and `N` being type-level naturals. I don't know much about F#, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27022278/18944437) seems to indicate that this is possible in F# as well.
2. In C++ one can use templates with [non-type template parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)#Non-type_template_parameters). If I understand it correctly, classes for the specific sizes that are actually used in the code are then generated at compile-time.
3. Haskell has something called [indexed type families](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html) that seem capture exactly the concept I am after.

Now, since C# and F# are both .NET languages I am primarily interested in point 1 above. Would it perhaps be possible to implement the types that I need in F#, and then provide them to my application as a library? The best would be if I could define only the type-level naturals in F#, and then use them in C# to define `Matrix<M, N>`.

Comment: The linked answer explains pretty clearly how to do that in F# and shows examples. Is there something specific that's not clear to you?

Comment: Yes, that answer shows how to define type-level naturals in F#, but I am not sure if it is possible to use these in C# to define `Matrix<M, N>`. Especially since the type level naturals will (in theory) be an infinite family of types, which I don't know that C# supports by itself. Also, if it is possible, are there some pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: I should clarify that I have never used F# myself; i have only become interested in it because of this specific usecase. I have some limited experience of functional programming from school, but that was long ago.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I just now also came across the concept of [Type Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/). Maybe this is the way to go?

Comment: I think that the linked answer in effect does create a type for each number that you actually use. So if your application has an upper limit for the matrix size, you can find a solution, else not. Has it?

Comment: @Martin521 Oh, I see. I would still have to explicitly create each type with `let one = S Z`, `let two = S one`, etc. But then it really isn't that much better than just creating classes `One`, `Two`, etc. directly in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using an [interface with a static member](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-fsharp-7/). In F#, you can define type-level natural numbers like this:

```ml
namespace TypeLevelNatural

#nowarn "3535"   // allow interfaces with static abstract members

/// Type-level interface that all natural numbers must implement.
type Natural =
    static abstract Size : int

/// Type zero.
type Zero =
    interface Natural with
        static member Size = 0

/// Type-level successor function.
type Successor<'t when 't :> Natural>() =
    interface Natural with
        static member Size = 't.Size + 1

/// Define 1, 2, 3, ...
type One() = inherit Successor<Zero>()
type Two() = inherit Successor<One>()
type Three() = inherit Successor<Two>()
type Four() = inherit Successor<Three>()
```

Then in C#, you can define a matrix like this:

```cs
using TypeLevelNatural;

class Matrix<NRows, NCols>
    where NRows : Natural
    where NCols : Natural
{
    public double[,] Values = new double[NRows.Size, NCols.Size];
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
var matrix = new Matrix<Two, Three>();

for (int iRow = 0; iRow < matrix.Values.GetLength(0); iRow++)
{
    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < matrix.Values.GetLength(1); iCol++)
        Console.Write($" {matrix.Values[iRow, iCol]}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output is:

```
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
```

Comment: Nice! It bothers me, however, that we still need to explicitly define each natural with `type One() = inherit Successor<Zero>()` etc. This makes it pretty much just a more compact version of what we can do in C# already, namely to define classes `Zero`, `One`, `Two`, etc. that implement an interface `INatural`.

Comment: What I would really like is some way to either generate the naturals as an infinite family of types, or to dynamically generate the types that are actually used in code (like I could do with templates in C++). But maybe this is a pipe dream?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that in .NET. Each type has to be explicitly declared, but you could use code generation to automate it for as many naturals as you want.

Comment: Using code generation is an interesting idea.

Comment: I accepted your answer. While it does not really solve my problem, that is likely because it is not possible to solve my problem in C# and F#, but this might be the closest one can get.